# Using UI-Router - Is it possible to set only single ui-view using regular syntax?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

In one of my templates , I have this code :

```
<h1>Route 1</h1>
<hr/>
<a ui-sref=".list">Show List</a>
<a ui-sref=".thing">thing7</a>

<div ui-view="left"></div>
<div ui-view="right"></div>
```

When I click the `.list` state - I do have a controller with the appropriate configuration :

```
....state('route1.list',
{
    url: '/list',
    views:
    {

        'left@route1':
        {
            templateUrl: 'route1.list.html',
            controllerAs: "vm",
            controller: function ($scope)
            {
                this.items = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
            }
        },
        'right@route1':
        {
            templateUrl: 'route1.list.html',
            controllerAs: "vm",
            controller: function ($scope)
            {
                this.items = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];
            }
        }
    }

})
```

This is working fine and I do see both views getting filled with appropriate data.

Now - when I click on the `.thing` state - I want only this view :

```
<div ui-view="right"></div>
```

To be loaded with data.

So obviously I should use this code :

```
.state('route1.thing',
{
    url: "/thing",
    views:
    {
        'right@route1':
        {
            templateUrl: 'route3.html',
            controllerAs: "vm",
            controller: function($scope)
            {
                this.thing = "I'm aaa";
            }
        }
    }
})
```

**Question**

When I have multiple view on the page , and I only want to touch a single view (not the others) — Must I still using this structure :

```
 .state('route1.thing',
    {
        url: "/thing",
        views:
        {
             ...
        }
```

I mean - Is there anything which allows me to apply the info into a specific view like in the *regular* format:

```
.state('route1.thing', {
              url: "/thing",
              templateUrl: "route3.html",
              applyTo:"right@route1" , // <-- Something like this
              controller: function($scope){
               ....
              }
          })
```

Comment: By design - state nesting is the answer. If some conditions should change only some views - move them into substate. There still could be more substates, each changing just a small set of all available targets...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we can do with UI-Router in this case, is file nesting...

Based on the [plunker created by Royi Namir](http://plnkr.co/edit/Tr8tzhqQXFWK961KHVvi?p=preview), I made few adjustment and there is [an updated and working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qazcGuSrfiaGDtRVeJA4?p=preview)

So, we have parent state **`'route1.list'`**:

```
.state('route1.list',
{
    url: '/list',
    views:
    {    
        'left@route1':
        {
            ...
        },
        'right@route1':
        {
            ...
        }
    }    
})
```

And we want to change just **left** or **right** part. As already said, we can do that with state nesting - but nesting anther the above state **`'route1.list'`** *(not under the grand parent `'route1'`)*

```
.state('route1.list.thing', {
    url: '/thing',
    views: {

      'right@route1': {
        ...
      }
    }
  })
  .state('route1.list.left', {
    url: '/left',
    views: {

      'left@route1': {
        ...
      }
    }
  })
```

And these links will change stuff as expected:

```
<a ui-sref=".list">
<a ui-sref=".list.left">this will change the left</a>
<a ui-sref=".list.thing">this will change the right</a>
```

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/qazcGuSrfiaGDtRVeJA4?p=preview)

Comment: I think i wasn't clear. It is not mandatory to click "list" first . I can click "left" without clicking "list"  --- if so do i still need substate like you did ?

Comment: For sure you should play with.. to see what you can achieve with and what without sub-states. But in general - UI-Router is a state machine. All its benefits comes from the changing states and buildin hierarchy with them. So, it is hard what is suitable in general.. it really depends. Does this help?