# angularjs ui-router - How to toggle `ui-view`

Tags: angularjs, view, nested, angular-ui-router, state

I want to have a button on `parent-view` to turn on and off the `ui-view`. Just like how `ng-show` works. How can I do that?

One idea is to have `empty.html`(that is empty) as child view and call it when we want to hide `ui-view`. But I believe it should be better than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you expected and as you suggested - the native solution with `UI-Router` is - state nesting. So, either parent or some child will just hide that view:

Parent

```
.state('parent', {
  views: {
    '': { templateUrl: parent.html},
    'toggle@parent': {templateUrl: notEmpty.html },
  }
  ...
```

Child

```
.state('parent.child', {
  views: {
    'toggle': {templateUrl: Empty.html }, // now it is hidden
  }
  ...
```

There is similar Q & A with working example

#### [Using UI-Router - Is it possible to set only single ui-view using regular syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33570713/1679310)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried actually using ng-show? You could apply ng-show to the div that houses the ui-view and just reference a function in your controller that sets it to false on the ng-click of the button.